# Android OpenGL ES - ingame scoreboard

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am currently working on an Android OpenGL ES 2.0 2D game and I need to implement scrolling scoreboard, something like this:

[image: my problem with the scoreboard]

but when there are so many players they overflow from the specified region (white). When I implement scrolling (using Matrix translation), the same problem happens on top of the list. Anyone can help me?

Comment: One approach would be to set the scissor rect.  This is done in window coordinates.

Comment: I need to see the background (I have an image there)

Comment: Draw the background, enable the scissor, draw the text, disable the scissor.  Alternatively, draw the blue border after your draw the text (or give it a higher z-order value) so the text doesn't appear on top.  If these don't work it might help to explain what you're trying to do in greater detail.

Comment: @fadden thank you it worked like a charm, if you will put it as answer I will mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use the [scissor test](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Scissor_Test) to limit where drawing occurs.  Set the scissor with `glScissor()`, enable it with `glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST)`, draw the text, and disable it with `glDisable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST)`.

Note the scissor is specified in *window* coordinates.

Another approach would be to arrange the drawing such that the blue border is drawn on top of the text, either by setting the depth or drawing it last.  (This assumes you're not drawing it with `glClear()`.)